# How to define variable which belongs to indexed set in AMPL

Tags: variables, indexing, linear-programming, ampl

I have a definition of variable v which has two indexes: p and k. Index p belongs to set P, and index k belongs to set K, for every m depot. [image: this image is the full description]

In AMPL, I already make set of vehicle k like this:

```
set vehicle{m in depot}:= 1..12;
```

then I try to make the definition of variable v, but it said m is not defined.

```
var v {p in route,vehicle[m]}>=0, <=1;
```

I already search for this kind of problem, but nothing matched with this. Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: I think you want: `var v {p in route,m in depot, vehicle[m]}>=0, <=1`.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I already did that, but it did not what I want. That syntax gives you 3 index of var v

Comment: With `set vehicle{m in depot}:= 1..12;` you declare 12 vehicles for each depot. So if two depots then 24 vehicles in total. You can also do: `set vehicle:= 1..24;` and handle which depot they belong in a different parameter. With this you can declare: `var v {route,vehicle}>=0, <=1;`Note that AMPL is correct and the mathematical notation in the paper is sloppy. AMPL is very strict, and that is a good thing.